# d3.js events registered but not triggering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, events, backbone.js, dom-events

There is a beautiful graph that I wanted to replicate (and then modify) found [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999). My project uses Backbone and D3.js written in Coffeescript. Each backbone.view has its own type of d3 plot. For the most part this has been fine, until now. For brevity I won't copy all the code from the link, I've done my best to replicate it nearly exactly (the major differencing being the data used). So here's the problem... The graph renders completely, events appear to be 'registered', but they don't trigger. I am trying to use D3 events NOT the backbone+jQuery events. So the actual code surrounding the events looks something like this:

(everything is in coffee)

```
@node = @node
    .data( nodes.filter((d)-> !d.children ))
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", ".31em")
      .attr("transform", (d)-> "rotate(#{d.x-90})translate(#{d.y+8},0)#{if d.x<180 then "" else "rotate(180)"}")
      .style("text-anchor", (d) -> if d.x < 180 then "start" else "end")
      .text((d) -> d.key)
      .on("mouseover", -> alert("hi"))
      .on("mouseout", -> alert("hi"))
```

This should look nearly the exact same as the example...  The text nodes (`text.node`) objects are what I want events to fire on. For the purposes of this example, I don't care what they do so long as they fire. I've inspected the nodes with dev tools in two ways. Both indicate that a listener has been added to the object.

1 => (using the console)

```
> d3.selectAll("text.node")
```

Reveals a list of text nodes all of which have properties: `__onmouseout: function....` and `__onmouseover function....`

2 => I've also inspected it by selecting the dom element (again in dev tools under the `Elements` tab) and in the right column selected `Event Listeners`. This also reveals `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

The **issue** is, nothing happens. Nothing at all.  I don't think this is a Backbone + Jquery + D3.js combination issue, because in simple bar chart adding the `.on("mouseover", ...)` to rectangles works perfectly.

Please let me know if there's any relevant information I've left out. This has been a rather stressful issue, and I'm not entirely sure what to include for this issue.

Comment: Are you sure it is not firing at startup? The way you have it the function will be called right away, not on a mouseover/mouseout event. Try creating `function myAlert() {alert("hi")}` which you call from the text element like this: `on("mouseover"," -> myAlert)`. Let us know what happens.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do this: `.on("click", function() { alert("hi");});`. By wrapping it in a function, you prevent it from being evaluated immediately.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I had tried both of these before posting this. After much struggle I finally found the problem, and will post it below.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after continuing and continuing to search for a solution I finally started from scratch removing all styles and everything else that renders on the page.   It worked. So the code wasn't bunk. Something else was interfering. I one-by-one added the other views back to the page. Still worked. I  uncommented css. Broken. It took me a while to wade through the CSS but eventually I found:

```
text{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

...so just ignore all the pointer events on every text object... right? because that sounds like a good idea.

With the line erased everything's working the way it should. Sorry to cry wolf.

Cheers,  gs

Comment: And is a good reminder that posting complete examples in fiddles/plunks can help everyone.